# Is Koval the operative mentioned in TNG: The Pegasus?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, star-trek-ds9

From TNG [The Pegasus](http://www.chakoteya.net/NextGen/264.htm):

> PRESSMAN: However, all that changed three days ago. **Starfleet
> Intelligence has an operative in Romulan High Command**. He sent us a
> message that a Romulan warbird had located a piece of debris in the
> Devolin system which was positively identified as being from the
> Pegasus. The warbird was then ordered to locate the rest of the ship,
> if possible, and retrieve it.

In [Inter Arma Enim Silent Leges](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Inter_Arma_Enim_Silent_Leges_(episode)) we learn that [Koval](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Koval) was working with Section 31:

> William Ross later revealed to Bashir that Koval was a Federation
> operative and had been **working with Starfleet Intelligence for more
> than a year**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably not. Ronald D. Moore says that he wasn't consciously trying to connect the episodes together (by using the name *Bellerephon* for Bashir's ship). That presumably also goes for intentionally dropping in a reference to a spy mentioned in that same episode.

More likely is that Starfleet have several high-ranking spies in the Romulan command, just as the Romulans have at several high-ranking spies of their own in Starfleet Command.

> Moore blames the British for his inspiration, though. “*The Bellerophon was a ship on which Lord Nelson sailed,*” he says. “*That’s where I plucked the name from.*” Interestingly, the mythic character of Bellerophon rode the winged horse Pegasus, which happens to be another name that Moore used for a starship, this one in The Next Generation episode of the same name. “*Yeah, someone pointed that out to me after the fact, but I wasn't trying to draw a connection between the two,*” Moore laughs. Nor was he trying to draw a connection between Pegasus's master and the Chimera, the legendary beast slain by Bellerophon (and coincidentally the name of the preceding episode). “*I didn’t even know that,*” he admits.
>
> <sub><sup>[The Deep Space Nine Companion](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=kDe3VS07YSMC&pg=PA661&lpg=PA661&dq=%22yeah,%20someone%20pointed%20that%20out%20to%20me%20after%20the%20fact%22&source=bl&ots=hSlsuAr5HU&sig=ACfU3U3AWE8U8VL41bqwOQpyZcjuFHHu8g&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwix6MuP-5LzAhWnzYUKHbSGAN0Q6AF6BAgCEAM#v=onepage&q=%22yeah%2C%20someone%20pointed%20that%20out%20to%20me%20after%20the%20fact%22&f=false)</sup></sub>